# The query operator 'TakeWhile' is not supported

Tags: c#, gridview

This is my code. I have created table `M_Operator` and I want to get the name from the table which has length of more than 4 characters.
but I am getting this error:

> The query operator 'TakeWhile' is not supported.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataClassesDataContext dbcon = new DataClassesDataContext();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Get();
        }
    }
    public void Get()
    {
        var Operands = (from a in dbcon.M_Opearators
                        select new
                        {
                            a.Id,
                            a.Name,
                            a.Salary
                        }).TakeWhile(a=>a.Name.Length<4);
            gridEmployee.DataSource = Operands; 
        gridEmployee.DataBind();
    } 
}
```

Comment: TakeWhile depends on the order of the set of items.  Is this what you really want?  Or do you want all element without regard of order?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because TakeWhile is not supported.

Try [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx) instead:

```
var Operands = (from a in dbcon.M_Opearators
                where
                   a.Name.Length > 4    // names longer than 4 characters
                select new
                {
                   a.Id,
                   a.Name,
                   a.Salary
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank u bro.. but I want to use TakeWhile Operator.. Plz Give me Solution If u have....

Comment: Want to use TakeWhile when it is not supported? You cannot - because it is not supported. So use something else instead.